# How to store geometry as string in QGIS model?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am building a model in QGIS that automatically projects a raster or vector layer to the appropriate UTM zone.  The principle is not hard; ultimately it's just an intersect.  However I'd like to avoid external file dependencies and include the UTM grid as a constant within the model itself.  I can use the GDAL algorithm `build virtual vector` but that requires an external file (in this case GeoJSON).

Is there a way for me to include the set of features as GeoJSON *string* within the QGIS model?